# Good keyboard supported Windows FTP client

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, ssh, sftp

I have checked so many SFTP clients already, but one is worse than other. But seriously... I need exactly the following features:

- Be easily usable using keyboard, and not only with mouse
- Be the GUI working FAST, and do not freeze all the time
- Support multithread connections so I could continue browsing the SFTP, while it's transfering files
- Automaticly update directly edited files
- Support segmented file transfer, so I could use my FULL network speed and not like 10% of it for transfering files (I have over 100Mbit download speed, so it's very boring, when I see 500KB/s or 2MB/s downloads instead if 10MB/s from high quality dedicated servers)
- Support private key based SSH encryption
- It should have a GUI interface of course, it doesn't need to be so super nice, just fast

So far what I found is the following:

**FileZilla:** Totally unusable without mouse

**TotalCommander:** It's fast, but it keeps randomly disconnecting, which is super bad

**WinScp:** It's GUI is very slow and often freezes and does slow file transfer, even if I use 9 threads

**FTP Voyager:** Totally unusable without mouse

**CuteFTP:** Totally unusable without mouse

**CyberDuck:** Randomly crashes

**SmartFTP:** Randomly crashes

**BitKinex:** This client was closest to my needs, however it failed to connect to some SFTPs, because of some Cipher issues :O 
I found this about these Ciphers, but after doing that BitKinex closes the connection to that SFTP server, so I have no idea about what to do...

I tried this solution for cipher issues: http://steronius.blogspot.sk/2014/10/ssh-no-matching-cipher-found.html

So seriously, is there any really perfectly working SFTP client for Windows? I am even able to buy it, if it's seriously good. Please suggest me a program, even a free or paid one, which is working properly.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are looking for something with a GUI, right? If so, could you add that (or maybe some more specific info on what needs to be graphical for you) to your initial requirements? If you are *not* requiring a GUI, on the other hand, have you also checked out [WinSCP's text-based scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)?

Comment: All right, so I need a GUI (added it to the requirements now :) ), since I wanna use it manually and not by programs. I use Windows only as a desktop enviroment, so I use Ubuntu or Centos on all my dedi server machines and VPS-s, and that's why I need a good Windows application for being able to handle these manual file transfers easily.

Comment: The speed is not because of some segmented stuff, but because encryption and security is not for free.

Comment: I don't really think it's related to that. If the software is coded efficiently, then the security related things shouldn't cause any visible lag / slowdown. Take a look at the TotalCommander FTP management for example. It's like 10x faster than the FTP management in WinSCP.

Comment: what about a combination of sshfs mounts and ranger file manager?

Answer (score 0):

[FlashFXP](https://alternativeto.net/software/flashfxp/) meets your requirements